# VSCode does not suggest auto import when re-exporting a default export in an index file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, import, export, intellisense

I'm working on a React app and came to this case.

**Input**:

- The folder structure:

  ```
  /ProductTypeSelection
    index.tsx
    ProductTypeSelectionView.tsx
  ```
- ProductTypeSelectionView.tsx:

  ```
  const ProductTypeSelectionView: React.FunctionComponent<ProductTypeSelectionViewProps> = () => {
   return <div />;
  };

  export default ProductTypeSelectionView;
  ```
- index.tsx:

  ```
  export { default } from './ProductTypeSelectionView'
  ```

**Desired output**
Right now I could import that ProductTypeSelection component like this: `import ProductTypeSelection from 'src/ProductTypeSelection'` but the VSCode does not suggest auto-import for ProductTypeSelection (just ProductTypeSelectionView).

So my desired output would be able to use that import syntax and get the ProductTypeSelection import suggestion from VSCode at the same time. I wonder if this is achievable, thank you very much.
[image]

**Tried**
This will work as expected but wondering if I could re-write this in 1 line.

```
import ProductTypeSelection from "./ProductTypeSelectionView";

export default ProductTypeSelection;
```

Answer (score 1):

You export a `default`, instead try:

```
export { default as ProductTypeSelectionView } from './ProductTypeSelectionView'
```

Comment: Using this way the import syntax would be `import { ProductTypeSelection } from 'src/ProductTypeSelection'`. I wonder if I could keep this syntax `import ProductTypeSelection from 'src/ProductTypeSelection'`

Comment: You can't.. unless you import it normally and export it as default. `import Product, export default Product`

Comment: Thank you, that's what I've tried, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can import like this:

```
export { ProductTypeSelectionView as default } from './ProductTypeSelectionView'
```